# Delete many Wordpress users thru mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I downloaded and manually filtered a the Users database from Mysql, and now I have the users I don't want to delete. How should I make the query?

I have 100 users and I just want to keep User ID:1, 2, 6, 8, 19, 22, 30 
and delete the rest.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use WHERE NOT IN(<insert your keep id's>)

Answer (score 2):

As you tagged it as a Wordpress, I assume you're using Wordpress.

Hence, Here's a solution you're looking for

```
$users = get_users();

$preserve_users = array(1,2,6,8,19,22,30); // IDs of users you want to preserve.

foreach($users as $user){
    if ( !in_array( $user->ID, $preserve_users ) ) {
        wp_delete_user( $user->ID ); // Delete user if not in a preserve user list
    }
}
```

### Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_delete_user

Answer (score 0):

Use `NOT IN`

```
delete from Users where id not in (1,2,6,8,19,22,30);
```

Answer (score 0):

Same as in SQL

```
DELETE FROM <table> WHERE Id NOT IN(<id's to keep>)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers above should do it but if you want a simple way to do it without the code then you will probably have phpmyadmin installed on your server. Go to yourdomain.com/phpmyadmin and login.

Then you can navigate to the wp_users table where you can pick and choose which users to keep. Down the bottom there's a select all and then you can just uncheck a few.